# Hide var data on ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making AJAX like function but I have problem that bad user can change the value into any other current user. So, how can I prevent this thing?

```
$live = 'user1';
$fol = 'user2';

function ajax(like){
    var data = 'like='+like+'&CURRENTUSER=<?php echo $live; ?>&TOFOLLOW=<?php echo $fol; ?>';
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: data,
        success: function(e) {
            $('#success').html(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Also I want to move this ajax function into `ajax.js` file, but i am have problem in getting the value `$live` and `$fol` of users because echo $live doesn't work on `.js`. 
So, is there any way to do this like Facebook, Twitter AJAX function does ?

Comment: Since it's client side javascript, you can't do much about it!

Comment: But how Facebook, Twitter's Ajax performs ??

Comment: And about your `ajax.js` file: you can use rewriting or add handler to open script with php!

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for apache web-server. For interpreting JS file using php, add this line to your `.htaccess` file:

```
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
```

And put your script inside `ajax.js`. One other way is using rewrite URL:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule  ^ajax.js$    ajax.js.php  [L]
```

And put your scripts inside `ajax.js.php` file. Of course, all these are if you want to show your URL as JS file.

at the top of your `ajax.js` or `ajax.js.php` file, before any kind of output, put this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
```

Comment: **How can i prevent bad users changing the value ?? Any idea bro that was my major question**

Comment: you can't. your values are given to user and he can do whatever he want to do with them!

Answer (score 2):

> I have problem that bad user can change the value into any other current user. So, how can I prevent this thing?

Of course you **can not** do that at all.

HTTP is a stateless protocol – so *each and every* request that reaches your server is to be **mistrusted**, period.

You have to check server-side whether the requesting client is authorized to request/perform whatever action it is he wants to trigger – f.e. by checking that the user id that is passed as the “current” user against the session where you stored your login information. (So when you have the id of the current user stored in there, then there’s no need to actually send it from the client any more in the first place.)

This is one of the most basic security principles of any web application – don’t trust *any* incoming request, until you have *verified* that the client has the appropriate authorization. So asking for how to “hide” any data that is send from the client is completely the wrong question – that would be what’s called “security by obscurity”, and that **does not work**.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many solutions for such problem.

1. Add one of follow user in session before page load so even you dont need to send data in ajax. Just need to confirm action and all data will be taken from session. Hence hackers cant modify users.(This is how i solved the problem in my project)
2. You can build an function like encode() & decode(). when you are using data in file encode() it first.Then at code end use decode() to extract the info. Since if invalid data came out mean some one has tempered and you will not execute that action. But you have to create such encode() & decode() yourself.

   ```
   $live = encode(user1);
   ```

At php end

```
   $real_live = decode($live);
```

3. Ajax request to when start php execution you can have a function like

```
    check_auth(user1,user2);
```

So even if some one used bad data your security rules can filter them.

Hope you can use any of them.

Comment: Wow Encode & Decode works pretty well with `base64_encode($str);` !! I have encoded `$live` and after it is passed to server `ajax.php` i have decoded `$live` on `ajax.php` which is working cool and this has hide the FormData **Bro is it going cool or this is not good ??**

Comment: yes thats good , but if someone come to know about your encoding method your effort will go to waste. Best option will be to use your own written encode() decode() so hacker dont have any chance, thats what big organisation do. But still it will keep you safe from most of naive hacker